# Grails Spring Security GET logout adds two slashes to URL

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I added the Config: grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false

And I added link to logout/index in my UI.

Clicking on that link, redirects me to myapp//j_spring_security_logout, which gives me 404 because of the two slashes in the URL.

Removing the extra / the logout works as expected.

What can I do?

Comment: The URI that the logout redirects to is the Grails Sprint Security config setting `logout.filterProcessesUrl`. Normally it's set to `/j_spring_security_logout`

Comment: I know, but why is it adding the / twice?

Comment: Hmm... well, redirect() when used with the uri parameter, like the logout controller does, prepends the context root (ex http://myapp/). Have you tried removing the leading slash from /j_spring_security_logout? You shouldn't have to do that though. Without changing logout.filterProcessUrl I've used this and it worked fine: <g:link controller="logout">Logout</g:link>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, was not related with Spring Security. I had this entry in Config.groovy:

grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8090/ehr/"

And was the last slash there that was causing problems, I removed the slash and it worked ok.